# Cannot access sn, givenName in LDAP

Tags: c#, ldap

I am very new to C# and I'm using LDAP to 1) validate a user's login credentials and 2) obtain additional information about the user for my app.  Our LDAP server doesn't allow some of the data I'm requesting to be given out anonymously, so I have to wait until I bind with the user's full credentials to pull the data.  However, even then I have not been able to obtain simple fields like sn, and givenName.  Using JXplorer I can see where these values are hidden during an anonymous connection, but with a full user/SSL/password combination I can see everytning in JXplorer.  I just can't seem to do the same via my code.

If I loop through the properties after my first FindOne(), there are 9 properties found (none of which are the ones I'm looking for).  If I loop through the properties after my **second** FindOne(), there are only 4 properties available.  Neither results seems to be impacted by PropertiesToAdd.Add("...").

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
public string[] Authenticate(string user,  string password)
    {
         string[] results = new string [2];

        //Concatenate serverpath + username + container
        //I.e.  "LDAP://ldap.disney.com:636/CN=donaldDuck,ou=people,dc=la,dc=disney,dc=com"
        DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(_ldapserver + "cn=" + user + "," + _topContainer);
        //User's password for initial verification
        de.Password = password;

        //initate anonymous bind
        de.AuthenticationType = System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer;
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(de);
        searcher.SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Base;

        //Search for first record
        SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();

        //Check results
        if (result == null) throw new Exception(ERR_NOT_FOUND);

        de = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

        //Return search results
        //results[0] = (string)de.Properties["mail"].Value;
        // results[1] = (string)de.Properties["givenName"].Value + " " + (string)de.Properties["sn"].Value;
        // Distingushed Name of the found account
        string DN = de.Path.Substring(de.Path.ToUpper().IndexOf("CN="));
        // Close search connection
        de.Close();


        // now bind and verify the user's password,
        de = new DirectoryEntry(_ldapserver + _topContainer);
        de.Username = DN;
        de.Password = password;
        de.AuthenticationType = System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer;

        //Obtain additional information
         searcher = new DirectorySearcher(de);
         searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
         searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName");

         SearchResult r = searcher.FindOne();
         de = r.GetDirectoryEntry();

        foreach (string property in de.Properties.PropertyNames)
         {
           Console.WriteLine("\t{0} : {1} ", property, de.Properties[property][0]);
         }

        //End obtain additional information

        //Validate password
        Object obj = de.NativeObject;
        de.Close();

        //if we made it here, we successfully authenticated
        return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   // validate given user credentials
   bool isValid = ctx.ValidateCredentials(user, password);

   // find a user
   UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

   if(user != null)
   {
      string surname = user.Surname;
      string givenName = user.GivenName;
   }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: I did see that as an option, but I assumed that was only for MS AD.  Will this work against a Unix or Novell LDAP server?

Comment: @user2023444: sorry - no - this is really only for Active Directory (which I thought you were using) - if not: please specify what you're using and what you're working against!

Comment: Marc, sorry I don't know what the LDAP server brand is, I just know it's not AD.  However, I did manage to solve this.  It appears that if the DirectoryEntry(path) constructor needed the full DN as part of the path in my bound search, not just the base.  Once, I did that it works fine.  Thank you for your help.